# How to replace the previous jar file in Ant

Tags: java, ant

I'm doing a build using Ant and generates a jar file at the end that I copy to a folder using the command below.

```
 <jar destfile="../../folder/job.jar"....>
```

however it looks like that it does not replace the old jar file when it generates a new one. How can I force it to replace the old jar file with the new one?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `<jar>` task [overwrites existing JAR files](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html)...

> The update parameter controls what happens if the JAR file already exists. When set to yes, the JAR file is updated with the files specified. When set to no (the default) the JAR file is overwritten.

If the `<jar>` task in your Ant script isn't setting `update`, then we'll need to see more of your Ant script to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

To replace an existing jar, use the 'update' attribute and set it to 'yes'. By default, update is set to "no".

So, for example:

```
<jar basedir="sourceDir" destfile="target/existing.jar" update="yes" />
```